# How to define a non-thermal state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, density-operator

I got a very vague question.
A thermal state is defined by

$$\rho=\frac{e^{(-\beta H)}}{Z_\beta},$$

where $Z$ is the partition function. 
I want do now calculations with "non-thermal states", but I'm not sure how define them. At the end in my calculations the only important term which arise is $<N>$, which is $$(\exp(\beta\omega_k)-1)^{-1}$$ for thermal states. I thought about to add some small flucations to that. $$(\exp(\beta\omega_k)-1)^{-1}+\mathrm{fluctations}(\beta,\omega_k),$$ where somehow the normalization should be build in. So any occupation numbers with $\mathrm{fluctations}\neq0$ would refer to non-thermal states.

Could someone comment on that, or does someones has a better idea?

Comment: Note that $\beta$ is not even defined for non-thermal states, and also that the occupation number $\langle n\rangle$ can always be written as $\langle n\rangle = (e^{\beta\omega} - 1)^{-1} + x$, for some choice of $\beta$ and $x$.  So I do not think there is a unique way to answer your question, unless you give some more information about the physics that you are interested in.

Comment: Thank you. You're right. If someone has an idea on that, please let me know!

Comment: An idea on what? I am saying that your question cannot be answered without a significant edit explaining what you are actually trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't specify the form of your Hamiltonian, but I'll venture that it might be something basic, like 
$$
H = \sum_{\bf k}{\omega_{\bf k}{\hat a}^\dagger_{\bf k}{\hat a}_{\bf k}}
$$
In this case a very simple and convenient toy model for a non-equilibrium state may be a displaced (or coherent) thermal state of the form
$$
{\hat \rho}\left(\{\alpha_{\bf k} \} \right) = \frac{\exp\left(- \beta  \sum_{\bf k}{\omega_{\bf k}\left({\hat a}^\dagger_{\bf k}+\alpha_{\bf k}^*\right)\left({\hat a}_{\bf k}+\alpha_{\bf k}\right)}\right)}{Z_\beta\left(\{\alpha_{\bf k} \} \right)}
$$
for some complex displacements $\alpha_{\bf k} \in \mathbb{C}$. Note that actually $Z_\beta\left(\{\alpha_{\bf k} \} \right) = Z_\beta$ (bar a unitarily inequivalent vacuum situation), but kept the notation just to point out its origin.

From this you may easily complicate the ansatz to convex superpositions of distinct displaced states, like 
$$
\rho = \sum_{\{\alpha_{\bf k} \}}{\lambda_{\{\alpha_{\bf k} \}}{\hat \rho}\left(\{\alpha_{\bf k} \} \right)}
$$
for some $0 < \lambda_{\{\alpha_{\bf k} \}} < 1$, $\sum_{\{\alpha_{\bf k} \}}{\lambda_{\{\alpha_{\bf k} \}}} = 1$. Or generalize to a continuum of $\{\alpha_{\bf k} \}$ sets, etc.